Replace attribute of element that was set using dangerouslySetInnerHTML
As I am new to React (I come from Angular), I am not sure if there is a "React" way of doing this, but I am importing a json file, which has a property called content which contains an svg string, it looks similar to this:
{
  "content": "<svg width=\"24\">...</svg>"
}

I then have a function to render the content of that json:
export interface IIconsObject { content: string; }

export interface IIconsProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'div'> {
  icon: IIconsObject;
  size?: 'small' | 'medium';
  color?: string | 'default' | 'class';
}

export const Icon = (data: IIconsProps) => {
  let content = data.icon.content;
  const size = data.size === 'small' ? 16 : 24;

  content = content.replace(/height="24"/g, `height="${size}"`);
  content = content.replace(/width="24"/g, `width="${size}"`);

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />;
};

Right now I am doing regex to replace the width/height, but is there a better way to do this, such as using a dom selector that selects the svg and then maybe using setAttribute like svg.setAttribute('width', size)?

This is fine with dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I think you should keep it this way if you need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
More React way:
useRef for access to span html node. spanRef.current will contain regular DOM element.
useEffect to make modification after content or size changes and react renders updated nodes.
export const Icon = (data: IIconsProps) => {
  let content = data.icon.content;
  const size = data.size === 'small' ? 16 : 24;
  const spanRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // manipulate spanRef.current 
  }, [content, size]);

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} ref={spanRef} />;
};

Note that you might need to remove [content, size] if your component gets rerendered without changes to those values because dangerouslySetInnerHTML will overwrite previous modifications.

does useEffect have any performance issues when there are lots of icons on a page?

I don't know whether it will result in any issues but it definitly will be slower beacuse this way dangerouslySetInnerHTML renders unmodified svg and useEffect modifies the DOM afterwards. This might trigger a couple of reflows and repaints

Might be late to the party but I'm here to suggest an approach using a library. At the end it would be very similar to @myrrtle's answer but the benefit is that here you wouldn't have to implement the DOM parsing logic yourself.
You could use html-react-parser which helps, as the name suggests, parsing HTML strings to React components. I prefer something like this because you have even more control with the parsing where implementing something like sanitizing the parsed HTML with isomorphic-dompurify or others becomes even easier.
In any case, something like this could do the trick:
import { useMemo } from "react";
import parser, { attributesToProps, domToReact } from "html-react-parser";

export const Icon = ({ content }) => {
  const parsedIcon = useMemo(
    () =>
      parser(content, {
        replace: (domNode) => {
          if (!domNode.attribs) {
            return null;
          }

          const props = attributesToProps(domNode.attribs);
          const children = domNode.children
            ? domToReact(domNode.children)
            : null;

          return (
            <svg {...props} width={50} height={50}>
              {children}
            </svg>
          );
        },
      }),
    [content]
  );

  return parsedIcon;
}

You can check the following CodeSandbox for a demo on how to use this:

